# Reading multiple bytes into a single value in TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow

I'm trying to read the label in a similar way as described in cifar10 example in TensorFlow:

```py
 ....
 label_bytes = 2 # it was 1 in the original version
 result.key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
 record_bytes = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.uint8)
 result.label = tf.cast(tf.slice(record_bytes, [0], [label_bytes]), tf.int32)
 ....
```

The problem is, if `label_byte` is bigger than 1 (e.g.,2), `result.label` seems to become a tensor of two elements (each of which is 1-byte). I just want to represent the consecutive `label_bytes` of bytes into a single value. How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a second decoder, decode int16 with it and take the first element as your label

```
shorts = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.int16)
result.label = tf.cast(shorts[0], tf.int32)
```

There's probably a better solution but it works.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I came up with too, and I guess it is such a waste to decode twice. I'm still looking for a better solution though.