# Resource exhausted error OOM when allocating tensor with shape[384,192]

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am now dealing with a medical image classification problem. The images are multiple slices of the patient's brain. The data has already been cleaned. I have 150 AD patients, 150 MCI(mild cognition impairment) patients, 150 NC patients(normal). Each patient has 96 dicom files or equally saying, 96 slices. Each slice is 160*160.

I use the Tensorflow cifar10 code as my template and to make the code work I have to change its read_cifar10 part. I change the code as the below link suggests.

[Attach a queue to a numpy array in tensorflow for data fetch instead of files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631852/attach-a-queue-to-a-numpy-array-in-tensorflow-for-data-fetch-instead-of-files)

First， I change the data to binary files with the my own python module load_img_M.py. To decrease data amount, I only select the middle slices, from 30 to 60.

```
    import numpy as np
    import dicom
    import os                      
    ad_path = '/home/zmz/Pictures/AD'
    mci_path = '/home/zmz/Pictures/MCI'
    nc_path = '/home/zmz/Pictures/NC'
    data_path =['/home/zmz/Pictures/%s' %i for i in ['NC','MCI','AD']]
    KDOWN = 29
    KUP = 61
    SLICESNUM = KUP - KDOWN + 1
    RECORDBYTES = 160*160*SLICESNUM + 1
    #load image from the directory and save to binary file
    def img2binary():           
        train_arr = np.zeros([100,SLICESNUM*160*160+1])
        test_arr = np.zeros([50,SLICESNUM*160*160+1])
        for p in range(len(data_path)):
            Patientlist = os.listdir(data_path[p])        
            for q in range(len(Patientlist)):
                Dicompath = os.path.join(data_path[p],Patientlist[q])
                Dicomlist = os.listdir(Dicompath)
                if q<100:
                    train_arr[q,0] = p
                else:
                    test_arr[q-100,0] = p            
                for k in range(len(Dicomlist)):
                    if k>KDOWN and k<KUP:#select the middle slices which have the most information
                        Picturepath = os.path.join(Dicompath,Dicomlist[k])
                        img = dicom.read_file(Picturepath)
                        #print(type(img.pixel_array))
                        imgpixel = img.pixel_array.reshape(25600)
                        if q <100:
                             # assign the label of the picture
                            train_arr[q,(1+(k-KDOWN-1)*25600):(1+(k-KDOWN)*25600)] = imgpixel #assign the pixel
                        else:                        
                            test_arr[q-100,(1+(k-KDOWN-1)*25600):(1+(k-KDOWN)*25600)] = imgpixel                                                
            train_arr.tofile("/home/zmz/Pictures/tmp/images/train%s.bin"%p)
            test_arr.tofile("/home/zmz/Pictures/tmp/images/test%s.bin"%p)
```

And the binary files look like this:

[How binary files look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK2R5.png)

Next, I change the cifar10_input module:

```
"""Routine for decoding the Alzeheimer dicom format"""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import load_img_M
import os
import numpy as np
import dicom

from six.moves import xrange  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
import tensorflow as tf

# Process images of this size. Note that this differs from the original CIFAR
# image size of 32 x 32. If one alters this number, then the entire model
# architecture will change and any model would need to be retrained.
IMAGE_SIZE = 160

# Global constants describing the ADNI data set.
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 160
IMAGE_WIDTH = 160
IMAGE_CHANNEL = 1
SLICES_NUM = load_img_M.SLICESNUM
NUM_CLASSES = 3
NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN = 300
NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_EVAL = 150
#define a dicom reader to read a record 


def read_ADNI(filename_queue):
  """Reads and parses examples from ADNI data files.

  Recommendation: if you want N-way read parallelism, call this function
  N times.  This will give you N independent Readers reading different
  files & positions within those files, which will give better mixing of
  examples.

  Args:
    filename_queue: A queue of strings with the filenames to read from.

  Returns:
    An object representing a single example, with the following fields:
      height: number of rows in the result (160)
      width: number of columns in the result (160)
      channels: number of color channels in the result (1)
      key: a scalar string Tensor describing the filename & record number
        for this example.
      label: an int32 Tensor with the label in the range 0,1,2.
      uint8image: a [slice, height, width, channels] uint8 Tensor with the image data
  """

  class ADNIRecord(object):
    pass#do nothing the class is vacant
  result = ADNIRecord()


  label_bytes = 1  
  result.height = IMAGE_HEIGHT
  result.width = IMAGE_WIDTH
  result.depth = IMAGE_CHANNEL
  result.slice = SLICES_NUM
  image_bytes = result.height * result.width * result.depth * result.slice
  record_bytes = label_bytes + image_bytes

  assert record_bytes == load_img_M.RECORDBYTES

  reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=record_bytes)
  result.key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

  # Convert from a string to a vector of uint8 that is record_bytes long.
  record_bytes = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.uint8)

  # The first bytes represent the label, which we convert from uint8->int32.
  result.label = tf.cast(
      tf.strided_slice(record_bytes, [0], [label_bytes]), tf.int32)

  # The remaining bytes after the label represent the image, which we reshape
  # from [depth * height * width] to [depth, height, width].
  depth_major = tf.reshape(
      tf.strided_slice(record_bytes, [label_bytes],
                       [label_bytes + image_bytes]),
      [result.slice,result.height, result.width, result.depth])
  # Convert from [depth, height, width] to [height, width, depth].
  #result.uint8image = tf.transpose(depth_major, [1, 2, 0])
  result.uint8image = depth_major
  return result
```

Finally, I change the distorted input. I delete those blocks for image preprocessing like cropping and flipping:

```
def distorted_inputs(data_dir, batch_size):
  """Construct distorted input for ADNI training using the Reader ops.

  Args:
    data_dir: Path to the ADNI data directory.
    batch_size: Number of images per batch.

  Returns:
    images: Images. 5D tensor of [batch_size, slices , IMAGE_SIZE , IMAGE_SIZE, 1] size.
    labels: Labels. 1D tensor of [batch_size] size.
  """
  #filenames = [os.path.join(data_dir, 'data_batch_%d.bin' % i)
   #            for i in xrange(1, 6)]#data_batch_1,2,3.bin
  filenames = [os.path.join(data_dir,'tmp/images/train%s.bin' % i) for i in [0,1,2]]
  for f in filenames:
    if not tf.gfile.Exists(f):
      raise ValueError('Failed to find file: ' + f)

  # Create a queue that produces the filenames to read.
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
  '''
  call the first function defined at the very beggining
  '''
  # Read examples from files in the filename queue.
  read_input = read_ADNI(filename_queue)
  reshaped_image = tf.cast(read_input.uint8image, tf.float32)
# Set the shapes of tensors.
  reshaped_image.set_shape([SLICES_NUM,IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_CHANNEL])
  read_input.label.set_shape([1])  
  # Ensure that the random shuffling has good mixing properties.
  min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue = 0.4
  min_queue_examples = int(NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN *
                           min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue)
  print ('Filling queue with %d ADNI images before starting to train. '
         'This will take a few minutes.' % min_queue_examples)
return _generate_image_and_label_batch(reshaped_image, read_input.label,
                                         min_queue_examples, batch_size,
                                         shuffle=True)
```

This problem is a 3d conv network problem. I use tf.conv3d and make changes so that the code could work:

```
def inference(images):#core code
  """Build the ADNI model.

  Args:
    images: Images returned from distorted_inputs() or inputs().

  Returns:
    Logits.
  """
  # We instantiate all variables using tf.get_variable() instead of
  # tf.Variable() in order to share variables across multiple GPU training runs.
  # If we only ran this model on a single GPU, we could simplify this function
  # by replacing all instances of tf.get_variable() with tf.Variable().
  #
  # conv1
  with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights',
                                         shape=[3, 3, 3, 1, 64],
                                         stddev=5e-2,
                                         wd=0.0)
    conv = tf.nn.conv3d(images, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(conv1)

  # pool1
  pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool3d(conv1, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 1, 2, 2, 1],
                         padding='SAME', name='pool1')
  # norm1
  #norm1 = tf.nn.lrn3d(pool1, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,name='norm1')
  norm1 = pool1

  # conv2
  with tf.variable_scope('conv2') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights',
                                         shape=[3, 3, 3, 64, 64],
                                         stddev=5e-2,
                                         wd=0.0)
    conv = tf.nn.conv3d(norm1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(pre_activation, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(conv2)

  # norm2
  #norm2 = tf.nn.lrn3d(conv2, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,name='norm2')
  norm2 = conv2
  # pool2
  pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool3d(norm2, ksize=[1, 3, 3 ,3, 1],
                         strides=[1, 1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool2')

  # local3
  with tf.variable_scope('local3') as scope:
    # Move everything into depth so we can perform a single matrix multiply.
    reshape = tf.reshape(pool2, [FLAGS.batch_size, -1])
    dim = reshape.get_shape()[1].value
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[dim, 384],
                                          stddev=0.04, wd=0.004)
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [384], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    local3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(local3)

  # local4
  with tf.variable_scope('local4') as scope:
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[384, 192],
                                          stddev=0.04, wd=0.004)
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [192], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    local4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(local3, weights) + biases, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(local4)

  # linear layer(WX + b),
  # We don't apply softmax here because
  # tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits accepts the unscaled logits
  # and performs the softmax internally for efficiency.
  with tf.variable_scope('softmax_linear') as scope:
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', [192, NUM_CLASSES],
                                          stddev=1/192.0, wd=0.0)
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [NUM_CLASSES],
                              tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    softmax_linear = tf.add(tf.matmul(local4, weights), biases, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(softmax_linear)

  return softmax_linear
```

I was afraid of the computer could not handle this large amount of data.So I chose the batch size to be 1 at first, hoping the code could run at least.Still I encounter the problem in the title. Actually I have very good Linux workstation.12G GPU titan xp, 64G memory. But I share it with my classmates. So the resources that are assigned to my account may be low. 
[My Linux GPU parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNmxD.png)

And it is even better if you can make some calculation to demonstrate why resource is exhausted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even for batch size 1 the network is too big. 
The problem can be found in the number of weights needed, not in the batch.
Try removing a few layers of the convonet or reduce the pixels of the 3d images and see where it's your limit.

Comment: Are there better ways to input the Dicom data? Does  queuing these binary files with 16 threading take up many RAMs?

Comment: I don't think your problem is the data. The memory is too small to store the weights of your convolutional network. Feeding the data in a different way is not going to make a significant difference in your case.

Comment: I resize to 80*80, and no more exhausted resources problem.